# Using KeyEnumerators in. Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Can Someone please help me convert below Obj C code to Swift 4.

I am trying to use `KeyEnumerator` in `Swift 4` . But it says value of type [AnyHashable: Any] does not have member keyEnumerator

```
- (NSString *)getParamsFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)data encode:(BOOL)encode {


    NSMutableString *params = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];


    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [data keyEnumerator];


    BOOL first = YES;
        id key;


    while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {
            NSString *value = [data objectForKey:key];

            if (first) [params appendFormat:@"%@=%@", key, value];
            else [params appendFormat:@"&%@=%@", key, value];
            first = NO;
        }


    return params;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate through a dictionary you can simply do:

```
let dictionary = [
    "first": 1,
    "second": 2
]

for (key, value) in dictionary {
    print("\(key)=\(value)")
}
```

or

```
dictionary.forEach { (key, value) in
    print("\(key)=\(value)")
}
```

More specifically for your code:

```
var first = true

for (key, value) in dictionary {
    let prefix = first ? "" : "&"
    let string = "\(prefix)\(key)=\(value)"
    first = false
}
```